# Select Material UI Tag Does not show error using Yup and formik

Tags: reactjs, select, material-ui, formik, yup

When nothing is selected, it should print the error, however, by inspecting elements I could see the error label but does not appear.
Another problem is that the label "Country" does not appear.
This happens only in the select tags in MUI and in TextField below which is the "Zip" tag it is okay.

```
    <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              required
              fullWidth
              label="Country" 
              name="country"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              value={formik.values.country}
              onChange={formik.handleChange}
              error={
                formik.touched.country && Boolean(formik.errors.country)
              }
              helperText={formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country}
            >
              <MenuItem value={"DE"}>Germany</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={"FR"}>France</MenuItem>
            </Select>
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to find an answer:
Try this out:

```
import { FormHelperText } from "@mui/material";

  <FormControl>
      <Select
        labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
        required
        fullWidth
        label="Country" 
        name="country"
        id="demo-simple-select"
        value={formik.values.country}
        onChange={formik.handleChange}
        error={
           Boolean(formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country)
        }
      >
         <MenuItem value={"DE"}>Germany</MenuItem>
         <MenuItem value={"FR"}>France</MenuItem>
      </Select>
      {formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country ? (
         <FormHelperText
            sx={{ color: "#bf3333", marginLeft: "16px !important" }}
         >
            {formik.touched.country && formik.errors.country}
         </FormHelperText>
         ) : null}
  </FormControl>
```

Hope it helped!!

Comment: Used it on my project and it worked perfectly well

Comment: Glad I could help. Take care bye.